# Eclipse EE format error

Tags: java, formatting, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse for Java EE developers, and I am getting this formatting error when pressing **CTRL + SHIFT + F**:

```
<%
    String loginError = (String) session.getAttribute("error");
        if (loginError != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("error");
            out.print(loginError);
        }
%>
```

The `if` statement has an extra *TAB* offset to the right. I want it like this:

```
<%
    String loginError = (String) session.getAttribute("error");
    if (loginError != null) {
        session.removeAttribute("error");
        out.print(loginError);
    }
%>
```

***Question:*** How do I fix this, and make it format like in the example above?

*Extra info:*

- I am using Eclipse Luna
- This is happening in a `.jsp` file, opened with a *JSP editor*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can depend on the exact version of the WTP Source editing jts.jsp you are using: there was a bug ([bug 400297: JSP formatter breaks tab policy in scriptlet](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400297)) which fixed it, but noticed another error: [400695: Extra indentation level when using spaces for the Tab policy](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400695)

The latter is still unresolved. Just for testing, you could try and set up the tab policy in Java,JSP,JS etc. editors/formatters to use tabs and not space, to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I already had tabs setup, but that is where I got this issue. Do you know when this bug might be fixed?

Comment: @Victor2748 no, I don't know when that bug will be fixed. Can you switch between tab and spaces, just to see if that makes any difference?